# Content inside div with fixed position just can scroll half of content

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a sidebar with a position fixed that can vertically scroll. But why when I scroll it, I just can scroll to half of the content of the sidebar I cant scroll until to the bottom of the sidebar.

As you can see in the first pic, there's still text follow us, but I cant scroll anymore. the second image is the image of the full sidebar

[image: First image]
[image: Second image]

[First image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmSKu.png)

[second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4ZdG.png)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  //OPEN FOR SIDEBAR MOBILE
  $(".toggle-menu button").click(function () {
      $(".menu-list-container").addClass("show");
      $(".menu-list").css("width", "275px");
      $(".notify").addClass("hide");
      $(".livetv").addClass("hide");
      $(".close-mobile").css("display", "block");
  });

  //SCRIPT FOR CLOSING SIDEBAR MOBILE
  $(".close-mobile").click(function () {
      $(".menu-list-container").removeClass("show");
      $(".menu-list").css("width", "0px");
      $(".notify").removeClass("hide");
      $(".livetv").removeClass("hide");
      $(".close-mobile").css("display", "none");
  })
})
```

```css
/* SCSS */
.navbar-mobile {
 

     position: sticky;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: row nowrap;
      align-items: center;
      padding-top: 15px;
      padding-bottom: 15px;
      background-color: $white;
      box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      z-index: 100;
    
      .toggle-menu {
        position: relative;
        width: 10%;
      }
    
      .logo {
        width: 50%;
        position: relative;
        img {
          position: absolute;
          transform: translateY(-18px);
          max-width: 134px;
        }
      }
    
      .navbar-right {
        width: 40%;
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row nowrap;
    div {
      width: calc(200px - 20px);
    }

    .livetv {
      a {
        color: $black;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-align: center;

        img {
          display: block;
          margin: 0 auto;
        }
        span {
          display: block;
          font: $small;
        }
      }
    }

    .notify {
      position: relative;
      button {
        position: absolute;
        top: -50%;
        transform: translateY(25px);
        background: none;
        border: none;
      }
    }

    .close-mobile {
      display: none;
      position: relative;

      button {
        background: none;
        border: none;
        position: absolute;
        right: 32px;
        top: 12px;
      }
    }
  }

  

    .menu-list-container {
        position: relative;
        max-width: 275px;
        height: auto;
        .menu-list {
          position: fixed;
          top: 0;
          bottom: 0;
          left: 0;
          width: 0px;
          //width: 275px;
          overflow-y: scroll;
          background-color: $white;
          transition: ease-out 300ms;
          z-index: 1;
          .header {
            background: url("../../asset/header.png") no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
            color: $white;
            .flex {
              position: relative;
              display: flex;
              flex-flow: row nowrap;

          .image-container {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;

            img {
              width: 65px;
              height: 65px;
              border-radius: 8px;
              border: solid 2px $white;
            }
          }

          .header-info {
            width: auto;
            p {
              font: $heading6;
            }

            a {
              color: $white;
              opacity: 0.7;
              text-decoration: none;
            }
          }
        }
      }

      .form-search {
        position: relative;
        border-bottom: solid 1px $gray1;
        input {
          width: 100%;
          height: 50px;
          border: solid 1px $gray3;
          border-radius: 8px;
        }

        button {
          position: absolute;
          top: 37px;
          right: 30px;
          background: none;
          border: none;
        }
      }

      .menu-content {
        border-bottom: solid 1px $gray1;
        ul {
          list-style: none;
          padding-inline-start: 0;
          margin-block-start: 0;
          margin-block-end: 0;
          li {
            a {
              color: $black;
              text-decoration: none;
            }
          }

          .live-tv {
            a {
              color: $secondary;
              font: $heading4;
            }
          }
          .live-tv:before {
            content: url("../../asset/icons/livetv-icon.svg");
            position: relative;
            top: 2px;
          }

          .foryou::before {
            content: url("../../asset/icons/check.svg");
            position: relative;
            top: 2px;
          }

          .saved::before {
            content: url("../../asset/icons/save.svg");
            position: relative;
            top: 2px;
          }

          .tv-schedule::before {
            content: url("../../asset/icons/check.svg");
            position: relative;
          }

          .livetv-regular::before {
            content: url("../../asset/icons/livetv.svg");
            position: relative;
          }

          .brandconnect::before {
            content: url("../../asset/icons/brandconnect.svg");
            position: relative;
          }

          li:last-child {
            margin-bottom: 0 !important;
          }
        }
      }

      .program {
        border-bottom: solid 1px $gray1;
        p {
          font: $heading4;
          margin-block-start: 0;
        }

        ul {
          padding-inline-start: 0;
          margin-block-end: 0;
          margin-block-start: 0;
          list-style: none;

          li {
            display: flex;

            .image {
              width: 48px;
              border-radius: 8px;

              img {
                width: 100%;
                object-fit: cover;
                border-radius: 8px;
              }
            }

            .image:last-child {
              background-color: $gray1;
            }

            .pl-20 {
              width: 70%;
              a {
                color: $black;
                text-decoration: none;
              }
            }
          }

          li:last-child {
            .image {
              display: flex;
              justify-content: center;
              align-items: center;
              background-color: $gray1;
              border-radius: 50%;
              height: 48px;

              img {
                width: auto !important;
              }
            }

            a {
              font: $heading4;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    .social {
      border-bottom: solid 1px $gray1;
      p {
        font: $heading4;
      }

      .social-list {
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row nowrap;

        .social-item {
          width: calc(100px - 20px);
          height: 43.75px;
          border-radius: 50%;

          img {
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            margin: 0 auto;
            transform: translate(13px, -7px);
          }
        }

        .facebook img {
          transform: translate(15px, -11px) !important;
        }

        .social-item:last-child {
          margin-right: 0 !important;
        }
      }      
    }

    .signout {
      a {
        color: $black;
        text-decoration: none;
      }

      a:before {
        content: url("../../asset/icons/signout.svg");
        position: relative;
      }
    }
 

     }
    
      .show {
        visibility: visible !important;
      }
    
      .hide {
        visibility: hidden !important;
      }

    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar-mobile">
        <div class="toggle-menu pl-10">
            <button type="button" class="btn">
                <img src="../asset/icons/menu.svg" alt="menu icon" />
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="../asset/logo.png" alt="logo" />
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-right">
            <div class="livetv pr-20">
                <a href="livetv.html">
                    <img src="../asset/icons/livetv.svg" alt="live tv" />
                    <span>Live TV</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="notify">
                <button type="button">
                    <img src="../asset/icons/bell-black.svg" alt="notify icon" />
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="close-mobile">
                <button type="button">
                    <img src="../asset/icons/close-black.png" alt="close-icon" />
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-list-container">
            <div class="menu-list">
                <div class="header p-20">
                    <div class="flex">
                        <div class="image-container">
                            <img src="../asset/avatar.png" alt="avatar" />
                        </div>

                        <div class="header-info pl-20">
                            <p>muhammad Rojali hernandez</p>
                            <a href="#"><span><img src="../asset/icons/" ></span>Setting</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <form class="form-search pt-20 pb-20 ml-20 mr-20" method="post">
                    <input type="text" name="search" required />
                    <button type="submit">
                        <img src="../asset/icons/search-icon.svg" alt="Search Icon" />
                    </button>
                </form>

                <div class="menu-content pt-20 pb-20 ml-20 mr-20">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="live-tv mb-20">
                            <a class="pl-10" href="livetv.html">LIVE TV</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="foryou mb-20">
                            <a class="pl-10" href="foryou.html">For You</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="saved mb-20">
                            <a class="pl-10" href="#">Saved Video</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="program pt-20 pb-20 ml-20 mr-20">
                    <p>PROGRAM</p>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="mb-20">
                            <div class="image">
                                <img src="../asset/program1.png" alt="program image" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="pl-20 pt-10">
                                <a href="#">Soccer Time</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>

                        <li class="mb-20">
                            <div class="image">
                                <img src="../asset/program1.png" alt="program image" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="pl-20 pt-10">
                                <a href="#">Soccer Time</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>

                        <li class="mb-20">
                            <div class="image">
                                <img src="../asset/program1.png" alt="program image" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="pl-20 pt-10">
                                <a href="#">Soccer Time</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>

                        <li class="mb-20">
                            <div class="image">
                                <img src="../asset/program4.png" alt="program image" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="pl-20 pt-10">
                                <a href="#">Kick Andy</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>

                        <li class="browse">
                            <div class="image">
                                <img src="../asset/icons/add.svg" alt="browse icon" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="pl-20 pt-10">
                                <a href="#">Browse Program</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="menu-content pt-30 pb-30 ml-20 mr-20">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="tv-schedule mb-20">
                            <a class="pl-10" href="livetv.html">TV Schedule</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="livetv-regular mb-20">
                            <a class="pl-10" href="foryou.html">For You</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="brandconnect mb-20">
                            <a class="pl-10" href="#">Saved Video</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                
                <div class="social mt-30 mb-30 ml-20 mr-20">
                    <p>FOLLOW US</p>
                    <div class="social-list">
                        <div class="social-item facebook mr-20">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img src="../asset/icons/facebook.svg" alt="facebook icon" />
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="social-item twitter mr-20">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img src="../asset/icons/twitter.svg" alt="twitter icon" />
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="social-item instagram mr-20">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img src="../asset/icons/instagram.svg" alt="instagram icon" />
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="social-item youtube mr-20">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img src="../asset/icons/youtube.svg" alt="youtube icon" />
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="signout pt-30 pb-30 ml-20 mr-20">
                    <a href="#"> Sign Out</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```